# Small script letter in text or math mode?

Tags: scripts

I know that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
\end{document}
```

produce :
[image]

but I want to know what is the necessary command to get :

[image]

Comment: One observation: the font `scr` is not used for texts. Don't use it to write words.

Comment: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligra/?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\mathscr` will give script fonts *in math-mode* only for upper cased letters; the shape will depend on the package used. As far as I know, there's no font providing this kind of fonts for lower-cased letters in math-mode. Don't use `\mathscr` to write regular, non-math text (it's intended to be used in math expressions).

In *text mode*, you can use the [`calligra`](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligra/) font, provided by the [`calligra`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calligra) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{calligra}

\begin{document}

\normalfont\calligra
ABCDEFGHIJ\par
KLMNOPQRST\par
UVWXYZ

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

I like mathematics. Mathematics is a language.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option would be to use XeLaTeX and a font like the one in the image.

Comment: the stix fonts include lowercase script letters suitable for use in math; these haven't been incorporated yet into the comprehensive symbols list.  the design is not as heavily sloped as most text scripts, so spacing and application of sub- and superscripts are somewhat less fraught than for most script alphabets intended for text.  beta latex support is available, or the (opentype) fonts can be used directly with xetes.